# My .exe program cannot run automatically after boot using Linux11

Tags: c#, linux, raspberry-pi

I am now using ***raspberry pi 4 model b*** for my project. The OS version for my pi 4 installed was ***Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)***.

I had completed a ***C# program***, released and put it into my pi 4. I using ***Mono Runtime*** to run my .exe program.

So, I can run my .exe file for version 1 but not for version 2. Version 2 is just a little bit editing in its interface. I used all of the method to let the V2 startup after booting but failed but V1 successfully startup.

Is anyone know where is the potential problem? Thank you.

---

Edited:

My V2 program is just V1 with a small modify for user interface only. V2 can be run manually but not startup after reboot. I wanna figure out why V1 can auto startup but not V2.

---

Comment: With all due respects, you're missing a lot of details from your post.  Does it throw an error?  What does your program do?  Could there be some code that works in V1 but not in V2?   Is there a core dump?   Did you try running the program in V2?  There's probably a host of other questions that I can't think of.  In essence, it's difficult to find the potential problem when we don't know what is really going on.

Comment: Did you check log files in /var/logs?

Comment: @ewokx hi there, my program can run manually by myself but not auto startup after reboot. The V2 code is just some small modify of the user interface. My program is RS485 Modbus communication

Comment: Sounds particularly like an issue with permissions/environment variable dependencies.

Comment: @ewokx i think so because V1 and V2 is just same program and only difference is the UI.

Comment: @jdweng Hi there, Im new to raspberry pi. May I know what should I check for log? syslog or authlog

Comment: Not sure.  Usually I check the times of updates using ls -lrt.  Look for anything that happened at time of failure.  If you have working code compare logs from working and not working.

Comment: Your question is missing too many details. How did you try to start it - crontab, /etc/rc.local, as a systemctl service? Does it have a GUI? Does it wait for any prerequisite services it needs, such as networking, or window manager? Which user does it start as?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hi there, I try to start my V2 program all ways, i had already tried crontab and etc/rc.local/, wont work for V2 but V1 can. Simple GUI as C# window form for displaying power meter reading.